# Is there anyway to unit test a UI application in QT

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, user-interface

I have done unit testing before in java using JUint and in c++ using QT Test, however i have just made a UI application using QT and most of the functionality that needs testing is graphically represented data in a QGraphicsView i was wondering if there is anyway of testing that the ui is behaving as expected as opposed to just checking the data that is being sent

my worry is that the data i could extract from the ui may be right as far as tests show but may behave differently when actually presented.

im aware this question is vague so feel free to ask questions and ill try to make it clearer to anyone who might be able to offer advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/?gclid=CI3_2vvB47YCFep7Qgod0ioAbw) from FrogLogic.

Comment: have you used this yourself? just wondering how it works. it says automated? and also is there any ability to write test code in c++?

Comment: I used it several years ago.  You can write test cases in a variety of scripting languages, but not C++, AFAIK.

Comment: I would love also to get feedback if its worth it now. We had a license couple of years ago and for complex UI it was hopeless..

Comment: @evilruff did you use something else instead after finding this solution to be inadequate?

Comment: Honestly I am looking for such tool already for years. (freeware or commercial). I am working as a head of IT development in a company which develops complex Qt applications for about 10 years. And since then we are looking for professional solution, but honestly I didnt find anything which worth money. The time we bought Squich it's support was ridiculously slow, application itself far fro being stable.. Unfortunately i cannot advise anything, at the end we have developed own set of tools for automated testing, but thats proprietary in-house products.

Comment: Squish changed dramatically in the last years, so would recommend to reevaluate. I know quite some large Qt projects that are using it. How good it works will also depend on what you're actually testing (widgets, QML, rendered views with opengl etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for advise, I for sure will have a look on it in nearest future.